# Alert Dialogue in Android-beginners

Tags: android, alert

I am trying to create a simple alert dialogue and I am following the steps from this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)
However,I am getting the error: `getActivity() can't be resolved` After some search I understood that `getActivity()` can be user defined, but I am not sure what should I make it do.

Here is what I have:

```
public void about(View v1) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
// Add the buttons
        builder.setNeutralButton(R.string.close, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                finish();//go to the previous activity
            }
        });
        
// Set other dialog properties
        builder.setMessage(R.string.myName);

// Create the AlertDialog
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();}
```

- What is wrong with this approach?
- Is there any other better approach you can suggest?
- oh, and what should `getActivity()` be used for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getActivity() is fragments method to get Activity.
If u are in activity u just need to replace this by YourActivityClassName.this

Answer (score 0):

```
// in a fragment
    new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
                            .setTitle("Alert title")
                            .setMessage("Alert Message")
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                }
                            }).show();
```